# Example of a sequence with a Cauchy subsequence and terms arbitrarily close

Tags: metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. Suppose there is a sequence $(x_n)$ in $X$ such that $(x_{2n})$ is Cauchy and $d(x_n,x_{n+1})\to 0$. The question is whether $(x_n)$ is Cauchy?

It seems intuitively that this is false, for there might be a sequence whose even terms come arbitrarily close to each other and the subsequent terms come close together as well but any two far off odd terms will still be separated for the consecutive small distances might add up to a large value.

Can someone through any light?

Comment: I think that $x_n$ is cauchy because say you have two odd terms then take the just next term for both and they will be very close and also the adjacent terms are close i.e $d(x_n,x_{m})$<=$d(x_n,x_{n+1})$+$d(x_m,x_{m+1})$+$d(x_{n+1},x_{m+1})$

Comment: @happymath: What if terms are not both odd?

Comment: if one is even and other is odd then the RHS will have one term less but they will still be very close

Comment: @happymath: Could you elaborate on your above comment. Which term will be less?

Comment: look at the answer posted by math_man that is what i had intended to tell

Answer (score 1):

Since $(x_{2n})_{n\geq 1}$ by definition of Cauchy sequence we have that for a give $\epsilon>0$ there is a $n_0$ such that for $n,m>n_0$ we have $d(x_{2n},x_{2m})\leq \frac{\epsilon}{3}$. An by definition of convergence to zero, we have that given $\epsilon$ there is $n_1$ such that $n>n_1$ $d(x_n,x_{n+1})<\frac{\epsilon}{3}$ . Now, supose $m,n >m_0= \max \{n_0,N_1\}$, then we have three possiblities:
m,n are evem numbers $m=2k, n=2s$, then
$$d(x_{m},x_{m})=d(x_{2k},x_{2s})\leq \frac{\epsilon}{3} < \epsilon$$ 
$m=2k$ is even and $n =2s+1$is odd, so by triangular inequality
$$d(x_m,x_n)\leq d(x_m,x_{n+1}))+d(x_{n+1},x_n)= d(x_{2k},x_{2t+2}))+d(x_{n+1},x_n)\leq \frac{2\epsilon}{3}<\epsilon
$$
or $m=2k+1$, $n=2t+1$, and  using the previous estimate 
$$d(x_m,x_n)=d(x_{2k+1},x_{2t+1})\leq d(x_{2k+1},x_{2t+2})+d(x_{2t+2},x_{2t+1})\leq
\frac{2\epsilon}{3}+\frac{\epsilon}{3}=\epsilon $$
Therefore, it is a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: Thanks...If you don't mind I cleaned up your answer a little.

Comment: No problem at all.